# Visual Studio for Mac - incorrect .net sdk location. Overwriting value when I make corrected update

Tags: .net, macos

My visual studio for mac is looking for the .net sdks in a path where they do not exist:
vs for mac (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS7Cj.png)

My sdks are installed in my usr/local/dotnet folder:
[location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFAZl.png)

When I update to this location in the VS for mac IDE i can clearly see the sdks. When I exit from this menu it gets reset to the path where it does not exist. And I am back at square 1. [updated sdks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r4hi.png)

How do I get this updated to the correct path so that I can target .net?

`` `This is the output of dotnet info: ``
`.NET SDK:`
`Version:   8.0.100-preview.5.23303.2`
`Commit:    3fe444af72`

`Runtime Environment:`
`OS Name:     Mac OS X`
`OS Version:  12.4`
`OS Platform: Darwin`
`RID:         osx.12-arm64`
`Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100-preview.5.23303.2/`

`.NET workloads installed:`
`There are no installed workloads to display.`

`Host:`
`Version:      8.0.0-preview.5.23280.8`
`Architecture: arm64`
`Commit:       bc78804f5d`

`.NET SDKs installed:`
`6.0.408 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]`
`6.0.410 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]`
`7.0.302 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]`
`7.0.304 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]`
`8.0.100-preview.5.23303.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]`

`.NET runtimes installed:`
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.16 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]`
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.18 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]`
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]`
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.7 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]`
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.0-preview.5.23302.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]`
`Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.16 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]`
`Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.18 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]`
`Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]`
`Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.7 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]`
`Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.0-preview.5.23280.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]`

`Other architectures found:`
`x64   [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64]`
`registered at [/etc/dotnet/install_location_x64]`

`Environment variables:`
`Not set`

`global.json file:`
`` Not found` ``

Comment: Please adjust the formatting and make it looking good.

Comment: Turns out you need to install the sdks via the ui of visual studio for mac. I had installed all of them from the microsoft web site.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're picking the directory, not dotnet file.
If you go to your directory(/usr/local/share/dotnet/), there you will see dotnet file(Unix Executable File), and in VS you need to select this file and then click **ok** button

Comment: I can't get to my usr/loca/shared/dotnet folder through the directory selector as this directory is inaccessible through finder. I am unable to select a .net sdk version in the screen where I manually enter the path. Maybe it is possible to manually enter the path of the unix executable? Would that be under dotnet/sdk/{version}/{executable file}?

Comment: @JimCampbell if you want to go to folder to check if dotnet folder is exist, you need to right click to **Finder**, in pop-up menu, you click Go To Folder, then you type /usr/local/share/ and press Enter. There you need to see dotnet folder

Comment: the dotnet folder exists. I am unable to get to it when I explore my directories through finder in vs for mac itself. When I click the three dots - if that makes sense?

Comment: You can tag(as color, by right clicking to folder and there you will see colors and select on of them) dotnet folder in finder, and in VS go to tag and select dotnet file in dotnet folder